# Yii2 : pjax in window popup

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, yii2, pjax

first, sorry for my english...

i have a CRUD in window popup,  but i can't update the grid in ajax success (insert, update and delete) without refresh page and closes modal.

In success ajax:

```
}).done(function(data) {
        $('#div-form').html(data.form);
        if(data.success){
            $.pjax.reload({container:'#pjax-resposta-possivel'});
        }
})
```

In action controller:

```
    public function actionSalvarRespostaPossivel()
    {

        $return = [
            'success' => false,
            'form' => null
        ];
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

        if ($post && $post['RespostaPossivelDetalhes']['id']) {
            $model = RespostaPossivelDetalhes::findOne([
                $post['RespostaPossivelDetalhes']['id']
            ]);
        } else {
            $model = new RespostaPossivelDetalhes();
        }

        if ($model->load($post) && $model->save()) {
            $return['success'] = true;

            $tblcacd_id = $model->tblcacd_id;
            $model = new RespostaPossivelDetalhes();
            $model->tblcacd_id = $tblcacd_id;

        }

        $return['form'] = $this->renderPartial('_formRespostaPossivel', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);

        return $return;
    }
```

In view:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false, 'id' => 'pjax-resposta-possivel'])?>

<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'emptyCell' => ' ',
        'summary' => "Exibindo {begin} - {end} de {totalCount}.",
        'layout' => "{pager}\n{items}\n{summary}",
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'chave',
            'desc_resposta',
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{update}  {delete}',
                'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 10%;text-align:center;'],
                'buttons' => [
                    'update' => function ($url, $model)
                    {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', false, [
                            'data-id' => $model->id,
                            'class' => 'btn-update-resposta',
                            'style' => 'cursor:pointer;'
                        ]);
                    },
                    'delete' => function ($url, $model)
                    {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', false, [
                            'data-id' => $model->id,
                            'class' => 'btn-delete-resposta',
                            'style' => 'cursor:pointer;'
                            ]);
                    }

                ]
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>


<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

I can just update the grid without closing the modal ?

Thanks

Comment: It's easy to forget but your modal is loaded through ajax, that means the javscript that refreshes the grid won't work because the grid doesn't exist. The easiest fix is to use either .on('click') for your javascript or put it on the same page as your modal

Comment: I'm using the .on('click' but dont work